# Detecting installed plugins under different browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser, plugins

I'm wondering if there is a way to detect installed plugins on different browsers.
So far I have found that you can "detect" plugins on firefox by trying to guess if chrome://path/to/some/plugin/image.gif exists.

This code for firefox looks like this:

```
<img src="chrome://firebug/content/blank.gif" onload="var a=document.getElementById('FireBug'); a.innerHTML = 'You are using FireBug';" style="visibility:hidden">
<div id="FireBug">You are not using FireBug</div>
```

I'm interested how does the code look in IE (more important to me) and if there are other ways to accomplish this task for other browsers too?

I want to know because I'm having an idiot client who claims he doesn't have installed plugins though I'm 99,99% sure he has. The problem is that some of those plugins are breaking parts of a web site admin control panel I've wrote.

Anyway I'd be glad to hear any tips,tricks,workarounds and etc for getting the plugin list of the popular browsers (ff,ie,opera,chrome,safari) :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This code will list all the plugins installed in the browser

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="example"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x=navigator.plugins.length; // store the total no of plugin stored 
var txt="Total plugin installed: "+x+"<br/>";
txt+="Available plugins are->"+"<br/>";
for(var i=0;i<x;i++)
{
  txt+=navigator.plugins[i].name + "<br/>"; 
}
document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry it took sooooooooo long to accept this answer. At the time this wasn't a standard and it only worked in Firefox and/or Chrome. This now seems to be supported widely so I'll accept your answer. :)

Comment: does not list user-installed plugins.

Comment: Does this work on mobile devices, more specifically on iOS based devices running safari ?

Comment: I haven't tested it for mobile devices, but I think, it might just work, you can try and let us know.

Comment: `navigator.plugins` is now deprecated, do you know what alternatives are?
ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/plugins

Answer (score 1):

You could try this: http://www.sliceratwork.com/detect-installed-browser-plugins-using-javascript

... but this is not going to detect browser add-ons like firebug, noscript, etc.

That script seems to detect only the following plugins:-

- Java
- 3D Markup Language for Web
- DjVu
- Flash
- Google Talk
- Acrobat Reader
- QuickTime
- RealPlayer
- SVG Viewer
- Shockwave
- Silverlight
- Skype
- VLC
- Windows Media Player
- Xara

Comment: I'll try it but I don't think that will help me :/

Answer (score 1):

This code will give you all the info you need:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>About Plug-ins</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
numPlugins = navigator.plugins.length;

if (numPlugins > 0)
  document.writeln("Installed plug-ins");
else
 document.writeln("No plug-ins are installed.");

for (i = 0; i < numPlugins; i++) {
 plugin = navigator.plugins[i];
 document.write("<center><font size=+1><b>");
 document.write(plugin.name);
 document.writeln("</b></font></center><br>");
 document.writeln("<dl>");
 document.writeln("<dd>File name:");
 document.write(plugin.filename);
 document.write("<dd><br>");
 document.write(plugin.description);
 document.writeln("</dl>");
 document.writeln("<p>");
 document.writeln("<table border=1 >");
 document.writeln("<tr>");
 document.writeln("<th width=20%>Mime Type</th>");
 document.writeln("<th width=50%>Description</th>");
 document.writeln("<th width=20%>Suffixes</th>");
 document.writeln("<th>Enabled</th>");
 document.writeln("</tr>");
 numTypes = plugin.length;
 for (j = 0; j < numTypes; j++)
 {
  mimetype = plugin[j];

  if (mimetype){
   enabled = "No";
   enabledPlugin = mimetype.enabledPlugin;
   if (enabledPlugin && (enabledPlugin.name == plugin.name))
    enabled = "Yes";
   document.writeln("<tr align=center>");
   document.writeln("<td>");
   document.write(mimetype.type);
   document.writeln("</td>");
   document.writeln("<td>");
   document.write(mimetype.description);
   document.writeln("</td>");
   document.writeln("<td>");
   document.write(mimetype.suffixes);
   document.writeln("</td>");
   document.writeln("<td>");
   document.writeln(enabled);
   document.writeln("</td>");
   document.writeln("</tr>");
  }
 }
 document.write("</table>");
}
</SCRIPT>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```